# PhoneGap Build 3.4.0 callback issue

Tags: cordova, phonegap-build

**The following works fine on PhoneGap 3.0.0**

However, when I upgrade to the latest version 3.4.0 on PhoneGap Build the callback is not triggered till the second time it's called for both the camera plugin (when calling navigator.camera.getPicture) and the Facebook plugin (when calling FB.login).

I tested this on Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini with Android 4.2.2 .
Any idea how to solve this issue using PhoneGap 3.4.0 and Phonegap Build?

Thanks!

Comment: Did you found how to fix this issue?

Comment: Nobe, still using version 3.0.0 ...

Comment: Please check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23653961/cordova-plugin-callback-received-after-second-plugin-call. Do you start your application in fullscreen mode?

Comment: Thanks! Yes I start it in fullscreen mode...

Comment: I have this problem on 3.6.0-dev even I do not use fullscreen mode.